# rsync closed failed error

Tags: ubuntu, nfs, rsync, nfs4

I'm getting close failed error when copying files to nfs share randomly. what could be possible reason ?
rsync  version 3.1.1

rsync: close failed on "/nfs_share/data/.99865579700_0.gz.LgfpIk": Input/output error (5)
rsync error: error in file IO (code 11) at receiver.c(860) [receiver=3.1.1]

Answer (score 0):

One of the reasons can be too big fie system cache. You can adjust it by adding

```
vm.dirty_background_bytes = 67108864
vm.dirty_bytes = 536870912
```

into /etc/sysctl.conf